# How to find the record by using array _id in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have record in db like this ,

```
  {
     "name":"xxxx",
     "college":"YYYY",
     "status":{"array":[
       {
         "_id":"1"
       },{
         "_id":"2"
       }]
     }
  }
```

I would like to fetch the record by using _id which is in array .how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this using two methods

1>

```
db.collectionName.find({"status.array._id":"1"})
```

2>

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$status.array"},{"$match":{"status.array._id":"1"}})
```

Comment: Agreed, but maybe you should elaborate the difference since these two are quite different in what they do and what the response looks like.